# Invoke-MgInvalidateUserRefreshToken cmdlet doesn't exist

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm starting to migrate my PowerShell scripts to Microsoft Graph module.

I'm using this site to see the new cmdlets:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-beta

I need to be able to do what I used to do in this part of the code:

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId $O365User.ObjectId -ErrorAction Stop
```

So I have checked that I needed to use this cmdlet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users.actions/invoke-mginvalidateuserrefreshtoken?view=graph-powershell-beta&preserve-view=true

The problem is that it doesn't exist on the module...
I'm using the latest version: 1.9.6

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.  I found this as a workaround:

```
$requestUri = "/beta/users/" + $MgUser.Id + "/invalidateAllRefreshTokens"
$revoke = Invoke-GraphRequest -Method POST -Uri $requestUri
```

Ref:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/1092

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that...
I'm using this code at the moment:

`Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$($O365.Id)/microsoft.graph.revokeSignInSessions" -Method POST`

Thanks @Jayce!